# Export Data From Excel to Oracle in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, oracle

GOOD DAY! I have question on connection from Excel to Oracle. I don't know what is failing!. My program migrates data and generates a log in another table, and the connection from Oracle fails.

Does anyone know why? It's my first program! Thanks!!!!!!!!!

```
Dim Password As String
Dim SQLStr As String
Dim Server_Name As String
Dim User_ID As String
Dim Database_Name As String

Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
Server_Name = "localhost"
Database_Name = "BDNAME"
User_ID = "ID"
Password = "PSW"

Set Cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Cn.Open "Driver={oracle};Server=" & _
    Server_Name & ";Database=" & Database_Name & _
        ";Uid=" & User_ID & ";Pwd=" & Password & ";"
connect = Cn
```

Comment: CAPITAL LETTERS ARE GREAT xD

Comment: jiji ji ok , tnks.. so........

Comment: Oh, I don't speak VBA, I'm just the annoying capital letters police

Comment: connection through oracle via ado is tricky. I suspect the issue is with the driver you specificed. `Driver={oracle}`. Make sure you have the correct drivers installed on your machine and you are referencing the correct ones as well.

Comment: the fail is "the name of the data source is not found and no driver was specified"

Comment: I think the sentence is wrong right where you mention it, but I do not know how to make the correct connection

Comment: Have a look through these https://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle/

Answer (score 0):

`Driver={oracle};` is wrong.

It depends on the driver/provider you have installed on your machine. I would recommend to use the Oracle Provider for OLE DB, you can download from [ODAC Runtime Downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/odacdeploy-4242173.html)

In this case the connectionString would be

```
Cn.Open "Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;Data Source=" & Database_Name & _
    ";User ID=" & User_ID & ";Password=" & Password
```

If you like to use other drivers, have a look at https://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle/